# WKWebView crashes on iOS 14 and above while loading payment URL

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, 3d-secure

My app crashes while loading a 3DS secure URL on WKWebView. It seems a JavaScriptCore  or libC++abi.dylib Issue. We are simply loading a URL on WKWebView, the issue is specific to iOS 14.0 and above and working well on iOS 13.x.
After adding the card details(especially ANZ Cards) we navigate to a WKWebView page which is a 3DS secure payment page. And the app crashes while loading the url in a few seconds with the message below:

```
2021-02-16 12:23:09.561862+0530 OrderMealCustomer[3370:81712] -[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002f7a5e0
2021-02-16 12:23:09.932686+0530 OrderMealCustomer[3370:81712] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002f7a5e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e1c8af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000010e063e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e1d76f7 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:]
 + 0
3 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e1cd036 _forwarding_ + 1489
4 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e1cf068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5 JavaScriptCore 0x000000011b3800ac _ZN3WTF6StringC2EP8NSString + 60
6 WebCore 0x000000011beb6637 _ZN7WebCore28getDefaultWebCryptoMasterKeyERN3WTF6VectorIhLm0ENS0_15CrashOnOverflowELm16ENS0_10FastMallocEEE + 839
7 WebKit 0x0000000125a84039 _ZN6WebKit15NavigationState16NavigationClient18webCryptoMasterKeyERNS_12WebPageProxyE + 65
8 WebKit 0x0000000125b3274b _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy13wrapCryptoKeyERKN3WTF6VectorIhLm0ENS1_15CrashOnOverflowELm16ENS1_10FastMallocEEEONS1_17CompletionHandlerIFvbOS5_EEE + 111
9 WebKit 0x0000000125e0e946 _ZN6WebKit12WebPageProxy21didReceiveSyncMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderERNSt3__110unique_ptrINS1_7EncoderENS6_14default_deleteIS8_EEEE + 1972
10 WebKit 0x000000012581863c _ZN3IPC18MessageReceiverMap19dispatchSyncMessageERNS_10ConnectionERNS_7DecoderERNSt3__110unique_ptrINS_7EncoderENS5_14default_deleteIS7_EEEE + 138
11 WebKit 0x0000000125b4df8c _ZN6WebKit15WebProcessProxy21didReceiveSyncMessageERN3IPC10ConnectionERNS1_7DecoderERNSt3__110unique_ptrINS1_7EncoderENS6_14default_deleteIS8_EEEE + 32
12 WebKit 0x00000001257f8c65 _ZN3IPC10Connection15dispatchMessageENSt3__110unique_ptrINS_7DecoderENS1_14default_deleteIS3_EEEE + 755
13 WebKit 0x00000001257f9ddd _ZN3WTF6Detail15CallableWrapperIZN3IPC10Connection16SyncMessageState22processIncomingMessageERS3_RNSt3__110unique_ptrINS2_7DecoderENS6_14default_deleteIS8_EEEEE3$_1vJEE4callEv + 541
14 JavaScriptCore 0x000000011b37996d _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEv + 573
15 JavaScriptCore 0x000000011b37a47a _ZN3WTF7RunLoop11performWorkEPv + 26
16 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e13738a CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
17 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e137282 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
18 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e136764 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 248
19 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e130f2f __CFRunLoopRun + 878
20 CoreFoundation 0x000000010e1306d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
21 GraphicsServices 0x0000000118d7bdb3 GSEventRunModal + 139
22 UIKitCore 0x00000001122aacf7 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
23 UIKitCore 0x00000001122afba8 UIApplicationMain + 101
24 libswiftUIKit.dylib 0x000000010f6c45f2 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
25 OrderMealCustomer 0x0000000108061bda $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
26 OrderMealCustomer 0x0000000108061b4e $s17OrderMealCustomer11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
27 OrderMealCustomer 0x0000000108064479 main + 41
28 libdyld.dylib 0x000000010f9363e9 start + 1
29 ??? 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*
```

Comment: Can you add the lines of code that lead to the error?

Comment: It's  webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
where url is https://sec.windcave.com/pxmi3/FD0290CD159B849373C89F3A326792E8C910AB444955E6C6CC
plese note: token string is long I haven't written the complete string here. webView is an instance of WKWebView

Thank You

Comment: @benc Received a reply from apple. It's a webcrypto error and escalated to WebKit team.

Comment: GTK. I'm assuming its the kind of problem that doesn't have a workaround... hope they can get you working soon!